# If statement with division - Power Query

Tags: if-statement, powerquery

[image]

Trying to enter an if statement into the query so that if the UOM says Btl and the Min Quantity is 0 that it just returns the Unit Price. If the Min quantity is not 0 but the UOM equals BTL then divide Unit Price/Min Quantity. If the UOM does not equal BTL, I want to divide Unit Price by the Case Pack.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Put it on separate lines and you can tell what you are missing

You need **if .. then ... else** parts

So your last row is missing the **then** and the **else**

```
if [UOM]="BTL" and [Min Qty]=0 then [Unit Price] else
if [UOM]="BTL" and [Min Qty]<>0 then [Unit Price]/[Min Qty] else
if [UOM]<>"BTL"  then [Unit Price]/[Case Pack] else
null
```